# How count rows based on two variables in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, count

I have a data frame and I would like to do the following: count the number of rows based on the 'CD_MUN' and 'acq_date' columns, and then create a column with these quantities, which I will call 'focos'. In addition, I would also like to calculate the mean of the 'frp' column.

My data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(acq_date=as.Date(c("2000-12-01",
                                    "2000-12-09",
                                    "2000-11-17",
                                    "2000-11-17",
                                    "2000-12-09"),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                 frp=c(100,200,300,400,500),
                 geometry=c("c(-59.7246, -15.4336)",
                            "c(-48.112, -4.5772)",
                            "c(-57.108, -17.4479)",
                            "c(-47.3609, -4.4691)",
                            "c(-48.4793, -2.7711)"),
                 CD_MUN = c(5105507,1506187,5106505,
                            5106505,1508001),
                 NM_MUN = c("Vila Bela da Santíssima Trindade",
                            "Rondon do Pará",
                            "Poconé",
                            "Poconé",
                            "Tomé-Açu"),
                 Bioma = c("Amazônia", "Cerrado", "Amazônia",
                           "Amazônia", "Pantanal"))
```

My expectation:
[image]

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to assume NM_MUN and Bioma ar properties of the CD_MUN, then this approach seems to be applicable to your case:

```r
f %>% group_by( acq_date, CD_MUN, NM_MUN,Bioma ) %>%
    summarize( frp = mean( frp ), Focos=length(acq_date) ) %>%
    arrange( frp )
```

Essentially group by all those variables that define a CD_MUN, calculate the mean and count the number of records in each group.

Comment: Thank you Sirius, I answered above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sírius, but the data frame did not return as expected. I did it like this:

```
df$focos<-1


df2 <- ddply(df, c("acq_date", "CD_MUN", "Bioma"), summarise,
                                        frp = mean(frp, na.rm=TRUE),
                                        acq_date = unique(acq_date),
                                        CD_MUN = unique(CD_MUN),
                                        NM_MUN = unique(NM_MUN),
                                        Bioma = unique(Bioma),
                                        Focos = table(focos))
```

I'm not sure if it's right, but I think so ...